# Parameters for release.sh to build binaries only for current platform

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to build Kubernetes from source using the release.sh script. However I can see that it build client and server binaries for many platforms which are not useful to me. How can I say release.sh to build binaries only for my platform? I can see that KUBE_SERVER_PLATFORMS and KUBE_CLIENT_PLATFORMS checks are done in hack/lib/golang.sh script. But how can I pass those values?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're looking to cross-compile, or specifically build a release, I'd recommend using `hack/build-go.sh`, it will [pick](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/lib/golang.sh#L491) the [host platform](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/lib/util.sh#L121) for you and just build on that.

Comment: I tried to run build-go.sh and got following errors. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d5517747746616aa8df. It seems like go can't find some dependencies. Should I set up some dependency management system for go before running this build-go.sh?

Comment: Sounds like your go installation doesn't have a compatible stdlib. Try what the failure output asks you to do: "stdlib pkg cannot be rebuilt since /usr/pkg is not writable by dimuthu. Make /usr/pkg writable for dimuthu for a one-time stdlib install, Or Rebuild stdlib using the command 'CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -a -installsuffix cgo std'".